# Dart Pub error on package install?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Dart worked until I updated Editor and now I get errors for existing and new projects. I tried a complete reinstall of Dart. I get the following message when I run pub install on web-ui for a new project:

```
--- Jun 11, 2013 10:25:11 PM Running pub install ... ---
Pub install failed, [255] Unhandled exception:
FileIOException: Cannot open file 'C:\Users\Phloxicon\Documents\dart\dart-sdk\bin\version' (OS Error: The system cannot find the file specified.

, errno = 2)
#0      _File.throwIfError (file_impl.dart:444:7)
#1      _File.openSync (file_impl.dart:310:17)
#2      _File.readAsBytesSync (file_impl.dart:363:26)
#3      _File.readAsStringSync (file_impl.dart:381:41)
#4      readTextFile (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/io.dart:71:68)
#5      _getVersion (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/sdk.dart:24:29)
#6      version (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/sdk.dart:17:30)
#7      main (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/bin/pub.dart:61:30)
```

It's right that there is no "version" file in that directory from a clean install. I added that file and got the following message:

```
--- Jun 11, 2013 10:23:42 PM Running pub install ... ---

Pub install failed, [69] Resolving dependencies...

Failed NSS_Init call.
```

I get the following when I create a new project:

```
--- Jun 11, 2013 10:26:17 PM build.dart --machine --full ---
file:/C:/Users/Phloxicon/Dropbox/dart/MyApp/build.dart
build.dart returned error code 255

Do not know how to load 'dart:uri''package:analyzer_experimental/src/generated/java_core.dart': Error: line 4 pos 1: library handler failed
import "dart:uri";
^
'package:analyzer_experimental/src/generated/ast.dart': Error: line 7 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'java_core.dart';
^
'package:web_ui/src/compiler.dart': Error: line 10 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'package:analyzer_experimental/src/generated/ast.dart' show Directive, UriBasedDirective;
^
'package:web_ui/dwc.dart': Error: line 12 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'src/compiler.dart';
^
'package:web_ui/component_build.dart': Error: line 25 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'dwc.dart' as dwc;
^
'file:///C:/Users/Phloxicon/Dropbox/dart/MyApp/build.dart': Error: line 2 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'package:web_ui/component_build.dart';
^


--- Jun 11, 2013 10:26:18 PM Running pub install ... ---
Pub install failed, [255] Unhandled exception:
FileIOException: Cannot open file 'C:\Users\Phloxicon\Documents\dart\dart-sdk\bin\version' (OS Error: The system cannot find the file specified.

, errno = 2)
#0      _File.throwIfError (file_impl.dart:444:7)
#1      _File.openSync (file_impl.dart:310:17)
#2      _File.readAsBytesSync (file_impl.dart:363:26)
#3      _File.readAsStringSync (file_impl.dart:381:41)
#4      readTextFile (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/io.dart:71:68)
#5      _getVersion (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/sdk.dart:24:29)
#6      version (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/sdk.dart:17:30)
#7      main (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/bin/pub.dart:61:30)


--- Jun 11, 2013 10:26:18 PM build.dart --machine --full ---
file:/C:/Users/Phloxicon/Dropbox/dart/Test02/build.dart
build.dart returned error code 255

Unable to open file: C:/Users/Phloxicon/Dropbox/dart/Test02/packages/web_ui/component_build.dart'file:///C:/Users/Phloxicon/Dropbox/dart/Test02/build.dart': Error: line 2 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'package:web_ui/component_build.dart';
^


--- Jun 11, 2013 10:26:18 PM build.dart --machine --full ---
file:/C:/Users/Phloxicon/Dropbox/dart/quiz_generator/build.dart
build.dart returned error code 255

Do not know how to load 'dart:uri''package:analyzer_experimental/src/generated/java_core.dart': Error: line 4 pos 1: library handler failed
import "dart:uri";
^
'package:analyzer_experimental/src/generated/ast.dart': Error: line 7 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'java_core.dart';
^
'package:web_ui/src/compiler.dart': Error: line 10 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'package:analyzer_experimental/src/generated/ast.dart' show Directive, UriBasedDirective;
^
'package:web_ui/dwc.dart': Error: line 12 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'src/compiler.dart';
^
'package:web_ui/component_build.dart': Error: line 25 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'dwc.dart' as dwc;
^
'file:///C:/Users/Phloxicon/Dropbox/dart/quiz_generator/build.dart': Error: line 2 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'package:web_ui/component_build.dart';
^


--- Jun 11, 2013 10:26:19 PM Running pub install ... ---
Pub install failed, [255] Unhandled exception:
FileIOException: Cannot open file 'C:\Users\Phloxicon\Documents\dart\dart-sdk\bin\version' (OS Error: The system cannot find the file specified.

, errno = 2)
#0      _File.throwIfError (file_impl.dart:444:7)
#1      _File.openSync (file_impl.dart:310:17)
#2      _File.readAsBytesSync (file_impl.dart:363:26)
#3      _File.readAsStringSync (file_impl.dart:381:41)
#4      readTextFile (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/io.dart:71:68)
#5      _getVersion (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/sdk.dart:24:29)
#6      version (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/sdk.dart:17:30)
#7      main (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/bin/pub.dart:61:30)


--- Jun 11, 2013 10:26:19 PM build.dart --machine --full ---
file:/C:/Users/Phloxicon/Dropbox/dart/sdgdsfg/build.dart
build.dart returned error code 255

Unable to open file: C:/Users/Phloxicon/Dropbox/dart/sdgdsfg/packages/web_ui/component_build.dart'file:///C:/Users/Phloxicon/Dropbox/dart/sdgdsfg/build.dart': Error: line 2 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'package:web_ui/component_build.dart';
^


--- Jun 11, 2013 10:26:19 PM Running pub install ... ---
Pub install failed, [255] Unhandled exception:
FileIOException: Cannot open file 'C:\Users\Phloxicon\Documents\dart\dart-sdk\bin\version' (OS Error: The system cannot find the file specified.

, errno = 2)
#0      _File.throwIfError (file_impl.dart:444:7)
#1      _File.openSync (file_impl.dart:310:17)
#2      _File.readAsBytesSync (file_impl.dart:363:26)
#3      _File.readAsStringSync (file_impl.dart:381:41)
#4      readTextFile (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/io.dart:71:68)
#5      _getVersion (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/sdk.dart:24:29)
#6      version (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/sdk.dart:17:30)
#7      main (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/bin/pub.dart:61:30)


--- Jun 11, 2013 10:26:19 PM build.dart --machine --full ---
file:/C:/Users/Phloxicon/Dropbox/dart/srtgdsfg/build.dart
build.dart returned error code 255

Unable to open file: C:/Users/Phloxicon/Dropbox/dart/srtgdsfg/packages/web_ui/component_build.dart'file:///C:/Users/Phloxicon/Dropbox/dart/srtgdsfg/build.dart': Error: line 2 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'package:web_ui/component_build.dart';
^


--- Jun 11, 2013 10:26:19 PM build.dart --machine --full ---
file:/C:/Users/Phloxicon/Dropbox/dart/test1/build.dart
build.dart returned error code 255

Do not know how to load 'dart:uri''package:analyzer_experimental/src/generated/java_core.dart': Error: line 4 pos 1: library handler failed
import "dart:uri";
^
'package:analyzer_experimental/src/generated/ast.dart': Error: line 7 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'java_core.dart';
^
'package:web_ui/src/compiler.dart': Error: line 10 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'package:analyzer_experimental/src/generated/ast.dart' show Directive, UriBasedDirective;
^
'package:web_ui/dwc.dart': Error: line 12 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'src/compiler.dart';
^
'package:web_ui/component_build.dart': Error: line 26 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'dwc.dart' as dwc;
^
'file:///C:/Users/Phloxicon/Dropbox/dart/test1/build.dart': Error: line 2 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'package:web_ui/component_build.dart';
^


--- Jun 11, 2013 10:26:20 PM Running pub install ... ---
Pub install failed, [255] Unhandled exception:
FileIOException: Cannot open file 'C:\Users\Phloxicon\Documents\dart\dart-sdk\bin\version' (OS Error: The system cannot find the file specified.

, errno = 2)
#0      _File.throwIfError (file_impl.dart:444:7)
#1      _File.openSync (file_impl.dart:310:17)
#2      _File.readAsBytesSync (file_impl.dart:363:26)
#3      _File.readAsStringSync (file_impl.dart:381:41)
#4      readTextFile (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/io.dart:71:68)
#5      _getVersion (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/sdk.dart:24:29)
#6      version (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/sdk.dart:17:30)
#7      main (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/bin/pub.dart:61:30)


--- Jun 11, 2013 10:26:20 PM build.dart --machine --full ---
file:/C:/Users/Phloxicon/Dropbox/dart/testest/build.dart
build.dart returned error code 255

Unable to open file: C:/Users/Phloxicon/Dropbox/dart/testest/packages/web_ui/component_build.dart'file:///C:/Users/Phloxicon/Dropbox/dart/testest/build.dart': Error: line 2 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'package:web_ui/component_build.dart';
^


--- Jun 11, 2013 10:26:20 PM Running pub install ... ---
Pub install failed, [255] Unhandled exception:
FileIOException: Cannot open file 'C:\Users\Phloxicon\Documents\dart\dart-sdk\bin\version' (OS Error: The system cannot find the file specified.

, errno = 2)
#0      _File.throwIfError (file_impl.dart:444:7)
#1      _File.openSync (file_impl.dart:310:17)
#2      _File.readAsBytesSync (file_impl.dart:363:26)
#3      _File.readAsStringSync (file_impl.dart:381:41)
#4      readTextFile (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/io.dart:71:68)
#5      _getVersion (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/sdk.dart:24:29)
#6      version (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/sdk.dart:17:30)
#7      main (file:///e:/b/build/slave/dart-editor-win-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/bin/pub.dart:61:30)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cannot open file 'C:\Users\Phloxicon\Documents\dart\dart-sdk\bin\version'
```

This looks your Dart installation is broken. That file should definitely be there when you install the Dart SDK, and pub can't work without it.

Are you building the SDK yourself, or just downloading a pre-built one?

Comment: Downloading a pre-built one. I tried deleting all things Dart from my computer and reinstalling again but that didn't work. In fairness, it has been some time since I stopped using Dart because of this issue so the new installations may well work. I'll give it a go when I get time.

Comment: OK, sorry for the trouble here. Let me know if you're still having problems with the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pub update` rather than `pub install` so that cached packages are updated where possible.

Then use `Reanalyze Sources` from the same Tools menu. Be sure to clear any logs before running the `Reanalyze Sources` so you can be sure it did a clean build.

If that doesn't get you completely clean, delete any `packages` directories you see in the project's tree, and any `out` directories that might be hanging around, as well as the `pubspec.lock` file. Then run `pub install`.

That usually gets me back to clean builds.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, none worked. I'll keep trying, though. Thanks.

Comment: @PhloxMidas I've just noticed that the first error message you get is related to the dart:uri package, which doesn't exist anymore as the Uri class has been moved into dart:core! Remove any imports of dart:uri and see how you get on with the latest SDK.

Comment: Do you mean remove them from the standard library functions? I don't believe I call dart:uri in my code. Is it that I use package:web_ui/web_ui.dart and that calls dart:uri? It doesn't make sense to me I used a clean install with a new project and I get this error but everyone uses the editor fine. Maybe there's another cache I haven't found?

Comment: @PhloxMidas It might be that the pub cache from your previous install is corrupted and not getting cleaned up then. I use a Mac for Dart dev and my pub cache is at ~/.pub-cache, but this issue (http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10715) shows where you might find the pub cache on Windows. After removing packages folders and pubspec.lock from your project (do not reanalyze), close Dart Editor and try removing the pub cache before starting Dart Editor again and pub install. As long as you haven't got any projects that are currently working with the Dart Editor this should be OK to do.